# PHP File Upload Restrictions

Tags: php

I want to put a restriction on the size of images uploaded.
Below I have condition for image size.

```
if ($_FILES["upload_attachment"]["size"] < 25000)) // Max File Size: 25KB
  {
  echo "File size exceeds maximum.";
  }
```

I want insert condition in this code.

```
   if ( $_FILES ) {
    $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($files['name'][$key]) {
    $file = array(
    'name' => $files['name'][$key],
    'type' => $files['type'][$key],
    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
    'error' => $files['error'][$key],
    'size' => $files['size'][$key]
    );

    $_FILES = array("upload_attachment" => $file);

    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post->ID);
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: 25000 bytes are not 25 kb. also you need to use `>` A better place might be the php.ini as the upload of the image has already finished before the php script runs. Google for `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: @mIH1 you didn't actually ask a question...

Comment: My question is how insert condition to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to check that early, before you proceed with file processing, so you're not making the server do any work if it doesn't have to.

Also, FYI, the upload size is specified in bytes, so if you want 25KB, it will be (25 * 1024) = 25600 bytes.

To incorporate that condition, you could do this. It gets a little gnarly, so I've added comments on the closing brackets to note which closes what. fe = foreach

```
if ( $_FILES ) {//if files exist

    if ($_FILES["upload_attachment"]["size"] < 25600) { // Max File Size: 25KB 

          //I would also recommend adding error handling early.
        if ($_FILES['filename']['error'] > 0){

            echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['filename']['error'] . '<br />';

        } else { 

            $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
            foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
                if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                    $file = array(
                    'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                    'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                    'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                    'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                    );
            $_FILES = array("upload_attachment" => $file);
                    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                        $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post->ID);
                    }//fe
                }//if
            }//fe
        }//if no errors (else)
    } //if size ok
    else {
        echo "File size exceeds maximum.";
    } 
}//if $_FILES
```